# Deleting 50 rows in 3 tables using IN () in SQL Server so slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I'm running a pretty straight forward delete statement query. I have 50 'file' keys and I want to delete them.  Our database schema looks like this:

- File - `UID` (int) column is primary key (with unique, clustered index)
- Version - `File` column is foreign key to `File.UID`, `DataLockerToken` column is foreign key to Cache.UID
- Cache - `UID` (uniqueidentifier) column is primary key (with unique, non-clustered index)

Version had to index suggestions from SQL that I applied:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc_VersionFile_DataLockerToken] 
ON [dbo].[Version] ([File] ASC) INCLUDE([DataLockerToken])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nc_VersionFile_UID] 
ON [dbo].[Version] ([File] ASC) INCLUDE([UID])
```

Relationships: File 1:M to Version 1:1 to Cache

Here is the query I try to execute:

```
DELETE [Cache] 
FROM [Cache] c 
INNER JOIN Version v ON c.UID = v.DataLockerToken 
WHERE v.[File] IN ( 241647, ... 50 ids in total ..., 244038 );

DELETE Version 
WHERE [File] IN ( 241647, ... 50 ids in total ..., 244038 );

DELETE [File] 
WHERE UID IN ( 241647, ... 50 ids in total ..., 244038 );
```

This takes almost 1 minute and I'd expect it to be practically immediate. The `File` and `Version` tables are simply metadata, while the `Cache` table actually holds the binary info for the file.

Here is a screen shot of the execution plan:

[image]

**UPDATE**: It must be something with the Cache table or the binary info inside, because if I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio, as I said it takes ~1 minute. Then if I run the exact same query (same keys, so obviously they are not there) again in Management Studio or even a C# console app, the query is immediate, so unless there is some sort of 'query caching' which I don't think there is, this points to the fact that the data being deleted is the problem versus a problem with the query?

With that minimal info, anyone see and glaring problems in the execution plan?  I usually rely on SQL to give me an index hint if needed (and I know you can't always trust SQL), but it isn't like this db schema is so complicated.

Let me know if there is a better platform to ask this question on if this is not the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

SQL will cache the query plans, so the 2nd time it will be much faster. you can clean the buffers and rerun the queries to see the difference (DBCC FREEPROCCACHE)

also notice the query cost for the deletes themselves. you dont have to do those anymore. and depending on what you query you barely get any information. for example, a select count(*) will result a lot faster since count is simpler then removing a row

comparing a delete on a fresh table vs a delete with no result is not really a valid comparison.

you could put the 50 id's in a clustered table. the IN clause isnt the best and you're re-using the same set several times. but i doubt that makes that much of a difference tbh

Answer (score 0):

With 50 records I would recommend switching to a temp table, and joining on it instead of using a large IN clause. This will make the execution plan static per run, and perform much more consistently.